# refresh flat-list in content

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base

I am using nativebase.

I want to have a pull refresh flatlist.

I have a AppContainer with the header, footer and content:

```
   <Container>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor={colors.primary} />
        {renderHeader(this.props)}
        <Content contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>{this.props.children}</Content>
        {renderFooter(this.props)}
      </Container>
```

Then I have the flatlist in the AppContainer:

```
   <AppContainer>
      <TransactionList />
   </AppContainer>
```

The TransactionList is the flatlist:

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={datas}
      extraData={this.state}
      renderItem={this.renderList}
      keyExtractor={item => item.item}
      onRefresh={this.refreshList}
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    />
  </View>
```

**But it does not show the pull refresh because AppContent Content is a ScrollList.**

How Can I solve it?

Comment: Can you try putting `bounces={false}` to Content? You maybe also want to add the `refreshControl` prop with the `RefrechControl` Component from react-native

Comment: bounces={false} doesn't work. how to add refeshControl. The problem I have is I can't change the AppContainer much.

Answer (score 0):

RefreshControl is react-native component, the official react-native documentation has shown an example of it with ScrollView ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol ), but it is the exact same props for FlatList :

```
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
      >
        <Text>Pull down to see RefreshControl indicator</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```